# Trigger to start a Screen Flow

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow

I would like to know is it possible to start a Screen Flow using custom trigger?

I tried searching but I'm only seeing samples for auto launched flows.

If it's possible can anyone provide me a sample?

Thank you and Happy Holidays!

Comment: given that triggers can be executed in non-UI contexts (API, data loader, ...) why would you want a screen flow?

Comment: @cropredy For example, when an Opportunity has been Closed Won we need to auto create a Project (Custom Object) BUT the currency is very critical and the Opportunity Currency is not always equal to the Project Currency that's why I'm thinking about creating a screen flow wherein users can set the currency before that Project is created.

Comment: You still need to consider that the API or Apex or REST or Data loader could close an Oppo; hence a better solution is to prevent the Oppo from closing until a user has provided a Project Currency

Comment: @cropredy I understand that, we don't use Data Loader to change the Opportunity Stage...

Comment: yes -- but in the future you might -- my point being that triggers execute at the database layer and the database layer should be agnostic of how the database is being updated (UI v non-UI).

Comment: Should I just add a button to trigger the screen flow?

Comment: sounds like a plan!

Answer (score 2):

Architecturally, it is incorrect for triggers to do anything that requires user interaction.

- Triggers execute at the database layer and as such, execute whenever the object is the target of DML.  Thus, triggers can fire for plenty of non-UI use cases such as data loader, REST API, ApexRest, Batchables, Queueables, Future, invocable Apex, etc.  While you might not be using those use cases now, you may later in time.

A better strategy is to

- Add a field on the Opportunity called `Project_Currency__c` that must be present before the Opportunity can close. You can use Validation Rules to enforce.
- In addition to the above, you can use the before update trigger to default this value for use cases where you don't need user input.
- In addition to the above, if the decision process for setting the currency involves asking questions, you can add a quick action that invokes a screen flow to guide the user, ending up with a value that goes into `Project_Currency__c`.